# How do you set ItemDisplayBinding for a Picker programmatically in C# using Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin

My model looks like this:

```
public class TaskFrequency
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FrequencyString { get; set; }
    public eFrequency Frequency { get; set; }
}
```

then I tried the following but didn't work:
ItemDisplayBinding = new Binding("FrequencyString");

I know ItemDisplayBinding is of BindingBase class. When I set it in XAML, it works fine.

Comment: you need to follow the correct procedure.  Please see this: [How to: Create a Binding in Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-create-a-binding-in-code?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: no, if you're just trying to bind to an existing bindable property then your code is correct.  See the [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/populating-itemssource#populating-a-picker-with-data-using-data-binding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make a code sample for your reference.

xaml:

```
 <Picker
            x:Name="picker"
            Title="Select ....."
            ItemsSource="{Binding taskFrequencies}"
            TitleColor="Red" />
```

code behind:

```
 public  ObservableCollection<TaskFrequency>  taskFrequencies { get; set; }
    public PickerPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        taskFrequencies = new ObservableCollection<TaskFrequency>()
        {
            new TaskFrequency{ FrequencyString="FrequencyString1", Id=1  },
            new TaskFrequency{ FrequencyString="FrequencyString2",  Id=2 },
            new TaskFrequency{ FrequencyString="FrequencyString3",  Id=3},
        };


        picker.ItemDisplayBinding = new Binding("FrequencyString");



        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
```

model:

```
 public class TaskFrequency
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FrequencyString { get; set; }
    //public eFrequency Frequency { get; set; }
}
```

Use the Bindbase like below works for me.

```
  picker.ItemDisplayBinding = new Binding("FrequencyString");
```

Screenshot:

[image]